# Issue Identity Using transaction preprocessor

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to create a new Identity in hyperledger composer

```
async function onAddParticipant(tx)
{
   let subject  = await getFactory().newResource(NS, 'Subject', tx.Email);
   subject.Id = tx.Id;
   subject.Email = tx.Email;
   let participantRegistry = await getParticipantRegistry(NS + '.MyParticipant');

   await participantRegistry.add(subject);
   let identity = await issueIdentity(NS+'.MyParticipant#'+tx.Email,tx.Email);
   console.log("Identity Issued ---------->", identity);
}
```

But it gives me Error ***ReferenceError: issueIdentity is not defined***
Looks like either there is another way to do this, or the identity issue and anything related to identity can't be done in tranaction preprocessor or smart contract.

I have seen tutorial doing this using Node API, but I want to do this as a part of Transaction Preprocessor

My transaction defined in CTO looks like this

> transaction AddParticipant {
>     o String Email
>     o String Token
>   }

Answer (score 0):

You are correct - this cannot be done within the Transaction.  The only classes available in Transactions are the runtime classes [listed here.](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/api/allData#runtime-api)